# Why there is time lag when using Kendo and angular JS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am newbie to Angular and Kendo,My case is like buttons other than edit must disappear for other users in the query screen and it should appear for the owner of the query alone.

Now it disappears after some time lag say one minute,why this lag occur?
Any help on this is greatly helpful for me....

On analysis,identified the below points:
-the function called in ng-show is not triggered immediately where ng-show is wrapped inside a template,then checked by assigning a constant value for ng-show still there is a delay in triggering the ng-show.But fixed style worked correctly example style=display:none..
-then i identified that angularjs directives are not invoked immediately after rendering kendoui grid row template, there is some delay to invoke the angularjs directives

Code:

```
$scope.showButton = function(userId){
    if($scope.loggedInUserId == userId)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
};


$scope.model.columns = [
                        { field: "name",title:"Name", width: 300},
                        { field: "userId",title:"User Id", width: 100},
                        { field: "lastModified",title:"Last Modified Date", width: 200},
                        { field: "visibility",title:"Visibility", width: 100},
                        { template: "<img title='Edit' src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/normal/png21/d_040_edit_normal.png' onmouseover=\"this.src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/active/png21/d_040_edit_active.png'\" onmouseout=\"this.src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/normal/png21/d_040_edit_normal.png'\"  ng-click='viewQuery(#=id#);disableSave(\"#=userId#\")' alt='Edit'><img title='Make Public' src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/normal/png21/d_150_team_normal.png' onmouseover=\"this.src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/active/png21/d_150_team_active.png'\" onmouseout=\"this.src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/normal/png21/d_150_team_normal.png'\"  ng-click='makePublic(#=id#)' ng-show='showButton(\"#=userId#\")' alt='Public'><img title='Make Private' src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/normal/png21/d_118_user_normal.png' onmouseover=\"this.src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/active/png21/d_118_user_active.png'\" onmouseout=\"this.src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/normal/png21/d_118_user_normal.png'\"  ng-click='makePrivate(#=id#)' ng-show='showButton(\"#=userId#\")' alt='Private'><img title='Delete' src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/normal/png21/d_030_delete_normal.png' onmouseover=\"this.src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/active/png21/d_030_delete_active.png'\" onmouseout=\"this.src='content/images/glacier/2.0.1/generic/normal/png21/d_030_delete_normal.png'\"  ng-click='deleteQuery(#=id#)\' ng-show='showButton(\"#=userId#\")' alt='Delete'>", title: "Operations" },                            
                       ];

$scope.model.gridOpts = {
        columns: $scope.model.columns,
        filterable: { extra: false },
        scrollable: true,
        height: "230%",
        pageable: true,
        batch: false,
        reorderable: true,
        sortable: true,
        editable: "inline",

 };
```

Comment: any idea or suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Without having a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to analyze, it will be hard to pin down the problem.  But I'll provide a possible solution that you can at least investigate.

Angular is only able to hide those buttons after it, and **everything it depends on**, has started up.  Which means downloading the angular code, waiting for everything else to load, parsing the HTML, resolving any data dependencies, etc.  At that point it will make modifications to the DOM (which is when your buttons hide).

There are several ways to handle this, from using ng-cloak, not showing anything on the screen until it's been modified appropriately, or hiding all the optional controls and just showing what the user does have access to after Angular loads.

Here is one option which I just used in a project.  Add this code at the TOP of your entry file (like index.html, default.html, whatever):

```
    .ng-hide {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Now apply the ng-hide class to any of those buttons you don't want to show until you know what they have access to.

By placing this at the top of the default file, it won't show at all until it's told to.  If you place it in a .css file, then it will sometimes appear briefly until the .css file it loaded, parsed and applied.

Another option is to look at [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).  You can try out it out here: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

The fact that it's taking upwards of 60 seconds I believe you said, leads me to believe that maybe it is waiting for required data to get [resolved](https://www.google.com/search?q=angularjs%20routes%20resolve) before it can analyze permissions.

If you don't understand how the resolve statement works in routes, you can read about here: 
http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/17/resolve-in-angularjs-routes-explained-as-story/

I'm not sure if that will fix your problem, but once you can create a jsfiddle then you'll have many more people jumping in to answer this question.